# How SQL Server database snapshots works?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to update my application and make available the SQL server data before there is a problem. copying the data from one server to another server is not possible because of the size and also the backup and restore option takes too much time that i do not have.
Are there any options available in SQL Server?

Comment: The question is *far* too broad and suitable for http://dba.stackexchange.com, once you describe what your needs are. You may be asking about database replication, high availability clustering, database mirroring, AlwaysOn. Each of these has different strengths and weaknesses. SQL Server's Books Online has entire chapters dedicated to high availability solutions. You should check them to see which option fits your needs.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with high availability directly, you should consider using SQL Azure or any hosted solution where failover is provided. You still need to backup though, for the 0.0005% chance that the entire cluster fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a script(file):

1. Right click database
2. -Tasks
3. -Generate Scripts

From here you can generate a script (with data or just the scheme).

Then I suggest you use the command line to restore the database, this is more memory sufficient.

Use these links for a howto:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702(v=sql.105).aspx
http://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/